# array rows where the random-integer elements may have different ranges

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider the following code fragment:

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.array([True, True, False, True, True, False])
val = np.array([9, 3])
arr = np.random.randint(1, 9, size = (5,len(mask)))
```

As expected, we get an array of random integers, 1 to 9, with 5 rows and 6 columns as below.  The `val` array has not been used yet.

```
[[2, 7, 6, 9, 7, 5],
 [7, 2, 9, 7, 8, 3],
 [9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 3],
 [5, 7, 4, 4, 5, 2],
 [7, 7, 9, 6, 9, 8]]
```

Now I'll introduce `val = [9, 3]`.
Where `mask = True`,  I want the row element to be taken randomly from 1 to **9**.
Where `mask = False`, I want the row element to be taken randomly from 1 to **3**.

How can this be done efficiently?   A sample output is shown below.

```
[[2, 7, 2, 9, 7, 1],
 [7, 2, 1, 7, 8, 3],
 [9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 3],
 [5, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2],
 [7, 7, 2, 6, 9, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to sample randomly between 0 to 1, then multiply with `9` or `3` depending on `mask`, and finally add `1` to move the sample.

```
rand = np.random.rand(5,len(mask))
is3 = (1-mask).astype(int)

# out is random from 0-8 or 0-2 depending on `is3`
out = (rand*val[is3]).astype(int)

# move out by `1`:
out = (out + 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 9, 3, 6, 2, 1],
       [1, 8, 2, 7, 1, 3],
       [8, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2],
       [5, 8, 1, 5, 6, 1]])
```

Comment: Very useful insight that I can use in other places!